# CSS - Indenting border in unordered list

Tags: html, css, border

```
.myClass .dropdown-menu > li {
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
```

This sets the border under every list item in my list. margin indents the text and not the border. Is there a way to achieve this, since I want my border indented as text. It looks like this now:

```
-----
  text
-----
  text
```

And I want

```
   ----
   text
   ----
   text

.myClass .dropdown-menu {
                border-bottom: 1px solid;
                margin-left: 5px;
            }
```

Margin indents both text and border, but as I previously said, I just need the border indented, leaving the text indentation as it is.

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li>Item 1 </li>
   <li>Item 2 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use padding to 'ul' for li border indentation.

Comment: You're going to have to post up more code than that. This issue isn't reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/9NVDg/

Comment: Seems to be working though?? Or am i missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/6BLJ8/2/

Comment: Problem is, the bullet gets indented too. I think I'm encountering the same thing @Mefhisto1 did, which is how to do this:

`code`
   ----------
-  text
   ----------
-  text
`code`

With the bullet OUTSIDE the list items. I seem to recall some time back in CSS1/2 there was an indent-able way of accomplishing this but can't seem to find it now.

(can't seem to make the "code" tag work so this is unhelpful.)

Answer (score 0):

you need use `text-decoration: underline;` or `text-decoration:overline;`depending on how you need to emphasize just text

with this decision when the text appears underscore automatically stretch the entire length of the text

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
ul.dropdown-menu { 
    padding-left: 5px;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this:

I changed the **HTML** structure to,

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><span>Item 1</span> </li>
   <li><span>Item 2 </span></li>
</ul>
```

and **CSS** is

```
.dropdown-menu li{
    list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-menu li span{   
    border-bottom:1px dashed;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dkrwtcxu/)